# add an element AFTER another?

Tags: jquery

when i use append it add an element WITHIN an element. i want to add an element AFTER an element.

eg.

```
 <div class="link">
       <input class="link" type="text" value="Skriv länk" />
       <br />
 </div>
```

how do i add an element after 'input' but before 'br'?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$("input").after("<p>Hello</p>");
```

After on jQuery doc: http://api.jquery.com/after/

You also have the [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$("<p>Hello</p>").insertAfter("input");
```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

Answer (score 2):

You should really add an id attribute to your input not only for performance but to be sure that you append only after that specific input:

```
<div class="link">
       <input id="textBox" class="link" type="text" value="Skriv länk" />
       <br />
 </div>
```

if using jquery

```
$("#textBox").after("<p>Hello</p>");
```

else

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("textBox");
var element = document.createElement("<p>Hello</p>");
textBox.parentNode.insertBefore(element, textBox.nextSibling);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// create your element
var $el = $("<div>");

// append after input
$("input.link").after( $el );
```