# Adding/creating an input with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have few search forms and each form has an input value with class **"search_input"**.

I want: on button click to add this:

`<input type="submit" class="searchbtn" value="Search" />`

next to each input 
`<input type="text" class="search_input" autocomplete="off">`.

Currently I am doing so using display none and on click im setting the display to block but the forms are too many so in order to save some kb's instead of typing that on every form, I'm asking if it possible with jQuery to add the input next to each `.search_input`

Thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [add an element AFTER another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126653/add-an-element-after-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jquery it's quiet easy to add control:

```
$('.search_input').after($('<input type="submit" class="searchbtn" value="Search" />'));
```

Comment: Thanks alot again. Give it another 4 minutes to accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var $input = $('<input type="submit" class="searchbtn" value="Search" />');
$(".search_input").after($input);

//OR
//$input.insertAfter(".search_input");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){
  $('<input type="submit" class="searchbtn" value="Search" />').insertAfter(".search_input");
});
```

see docs: http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addSubmitButtons').click(function(e){
    $('.search_input').after('<input type="submit" class="searchbtn" value="Search" />');
});
```